# How to reuse SSH tunnel in Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, ssh-tunnel

I have to create a k8s job via Terraform and somehow organize the mechanism of waiting for this job to be completed (since Terraform fails to do this https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/534). I figured out nothing better than using a null resource with a command that waits for k8s job (namely `kubectl wait`). This stuff will be executed in a Docker container on a CI. Moreover, I need to go through the Bastion to get to the k8s cluster. I use an SSH tunnel for that:

```
provider "ssh" {
  port = ....
}
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_context         = "..."
  config_context_cluster = "..."
  host                   = "api.${k8s_host}:${data.ssh_tunnel.k8s.port}"
}

data "ssh_tunnel" "k8s" {
  host           = "bastion.....com"
  local_address  = "localhost:0"
  remote_address = "api.${k8s_host}:443"
}
```

All k8s resources successfully create so I assume that SSH tunnel works fine. But how to use it for a null resource?
Here is it:

```
resource "null_resource" "wait" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    connection {
      type = "ssh"
      bastion_host = data.ssh_tunnel.k8s.host
      bastion_private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
      bastion_port = data.ssh_tunnel.k8s.port
      host = "api.${k8s_host}"
      port = 443
    }
    command = "kubectl wait ...."
  }
  triggers = {
    job_ids = join(", ", kubernetes_job.a-job.*.id)
  }
}
```

But no luck, I got "The connection to the server api.${k8s_host} was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

So there are two questions:
1. How to wait for a job in a different way
2. If 1 is impossible (I'm sure that it is) how to reuse the SSH tunnel in the right way.

P.S Yes, I read the documentation https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html but I definitely do smth wrong.

Comment: Are You using some custom ssh tunnel provider ?

Comment: @AlexVorona, I think yes. Maybe there is a root cause?

Comment: It's just unclear how actual tunneling happens with custom tunnel provider. Pls update your question with details of ssh tunnel provider you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to reuse SSH tunnel opened by Terraform:

```
resource "null_resource" "wait" {
provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "kubectl wait --server=https://api.${k8s_host}:${data.ssh_tunnel.k8s.port} --for=condition=complete --timeout=3000s job/a-job"
  }
  triggers = {
    job_ids = join(", ", kubernetes_job.a-job.*.id)
  }
}
```